# How to make a GridItem use all of the available space in a LazyVGrid?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like the 2nd column of my LazyVGrid to fill all of the available space (a bit like `flex:1` in css). I should be able to do it by using `.flexible()`, but I can't get it to work

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help!

my code:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [
    GridItem(),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
]) {
    ProfilePicture()
    ProfilePicture()
    ProfilePicture()
    ProfilePicture()
}
```

screenshots:

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L22Fl.png)

[what I get instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQeqJ.png)

n.b.

- I don't want to use `.fixed(40)` for the first GridItem: I want its width to remain dynamic
- `ProfilePicture()` is just a clipped image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give a use case, or a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it is a bit difficult to determine what you do want, other than the second image. You can't produce that with `GridItem.Size`. You can make that look by setting the `alignment` on the `LazyVGrid` like this:

```
struct GridItemAvailSpace: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(),
        GridItem()
    ]
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading) {
            ProfilePicture()
            ProfilePicture()
            ProfilePicture()
            ProfilePicture()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. yes, it looks like it's impossible without specifying a fixed size for the first column.. so I guess I'll just do that. thanks again!

Comment: When you ask questions in the future, an MRE and use case will get you much better answers, otherwise we are simply guessing.